# Mirror of Michigan State University's Python geoprocessing course materials

Tags: python, geoprocessing, education

Been learning geoprocessing with Python using MSU's [GEOG 825](https://www.msu.edu/~ashton/classes/825/weekly.html) ( python geoprocessing ) course. Unfortunately the link is dead now. I know this is a long shot but does anybody have a copy of the materials from that course? I would really like to finish it.

Already checked out the other online Python geoprocessing courses. Found one in [Penn State](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/17) and on [Utah State](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/). Those focus on using tools though, whether they be ogr/gdal or ArcGIS' arcpy/arcgisscripting. Only Michigan State U's course discusses the algorithms and data structures as far as I know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the Wayback Machine at the Internet Archive has a [cached copy of the weekly outline page from Jun 29 2007](http://web.archive.org/web/20070629085051/http://www.msu.edu/~ashton/classes/825/weekly.html).  However, it looks like the links to the .zip and .py files used in the labs were not cached.

I would also encourage you to contact the professor who ran the course and hosted the information on his webspace.  It's likely [Associate Professor of Geography Ashton Shortridge](https://www.msu.edu/~ashton/) didn't know that folks on the internet interested in GIS were using his materials as a resource.  If you send him a polite and professional email explaining your situation, I'd like to think he would be delighted to help you out.  Note that according to his website, he's teaching in China this semester so he may not be responding to email as quickly.

Comment: Already checked the Internet Archive and emailed Professor Ashton. I just thought I'd explore other options :) Thanks for the answers though.

Comment: Still no response from Professor Ashton. I guess I'll just leave this question for a couple of days. Just in case somebody has a copy. If not, I'll accept your answer and close this. I'll share the course materials if Prof Ashton will share them ( with his permission of course ) :)

Answer (score 5):

I teach a Python geoprocessing course every 2 years...last taught Spring 2013,
next taught this spring 2013: http://nrm.salrm.uaf.edu/~dverbyla/nrm638/index.html

Comment: Thanks but that's not quite what I was looking for. The one I saw discusses algorithms and spatial data structures. Nice class though.

Answer (score 1):

I have started to watch some videos from a Python course from MIT that seems ok.  Here's the link I use:
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/

Comment: Halfway done with those videos :) Those are for general computation though. I'm looking for courses specifically on Python geoprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/17

I used it to start out in Python. Need to go back and visit the last of the classes.

Comment: Thanks but that one's ArcGIS centric. Doesn't discuss spatial data structures, either.